# Is partial immutability a good practice?

Tags: javascript, redux, immutability, immutable.js

Forgive the extremely simplistic example but I was wondering what is the difference between the following two approaches when you need to use an obj's value without modifying the deeply nested properties of it using immutablejs or any other similar libraires:

```
//case1
var imm_a = {'names':['Joe', 'Jack'], 'owns':{'car': ['Toyota','Ferrari']}};
var a = Immutable.fromJS(imm_a);
a = a.setIn(['owns','car', 0], 'Ford');
//...a bunch of other modifications using immutable.js methods

console.log(a.toJS()); // using the changed value
console.log(imm_a); // imm_a has not changed


//case2
var imm_b = {'names':['Joe', 'Jack'], 'owns':{'car': ['Toyota','Ferrari']}};
var b = Immutable.fromJS(imm_b);
b = b.toJS();
b.owns.car[0] = 'Ford';
//...a bunch of other modifications using native javascript methods

console.log(b); // using the changed value
console.log(imm_b); // imm_b has not changed
```

In both above cases we have an object (imm_a and imm_b) with deeply nested props that we don't want to mutate but we need to use their modified values. In case 1 we create an Immutable obj and directly modify it using Immutable.js methods, in the second case after we created an Immutable object we create a native Javascript variable from it so that we can work easier with it using direct assignments and other native javascript methods. In both approaches we reach our goal which was to keep imm_a and imm_b unmutated but I find the second approach much easier for the simplicity of modifications. But is there any difference? Which one is recommended as a better practice?

PS: In neither of those case I care about immutability of `b` or `a`, I only need `imm_a` and `imm_b` to remain unchanged. A common use case would be a Redux app where the new state is dependant on the old state and you need to modify the old state value before returning it as new state. `a` and `b` are local temporary variables here. Question is, is it ok to directly modify them as long as I don't rely on them having persistent values? Or if I use immutable practices I need to treat everything as immutable?

Answer (score 0):

The second example entirely defeats the purpose of using ImmutableJS, because you're mutating the contents of the `b` Javascript object. One of the main points of ImmutableJS is that if you modify an object, you get a completely new object back.

In this simple example it won't have any effects, but the benefit of writing immutable code is that anyone else who has a reference to `a` knows it will never change and it will always have the same value after they get it. In your second example, since you mutate `b` in place, any other code that has a reference to `b` will have the "rug pulled out from under them" so to speak, since your local updates will also happen to their reference to the object.

If you don't use ImmutableJS to ensure actual immutability, you are better off not using it for now. It adds non-trivial overhead work to a program.

Comment: I understand `b` is changing here but `a` is what I'm caring about. Imagine a scenario where some objects need to remain unchanged throughout the execution of the application but some other local ones are ok to mutate. An example could be the State in a React/Redux app where a deeply nested new State is dependent on the old one. In this case why can't I create a mutable local value `b` to hold the values needed only in order to return a new State without changing the old one. Why should I be using immutablejs methods here rather than just playing with the values in place?

Comment: Again, if you're not writing immutable code, you probably don't need immutablejs. consistency, style, and understanding of keeping everything immutable is why you would choose the first.